# Register the Best Model from AzureML AutoML as Custom Model

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service, mlflow, automl

The AzureML AutoML best model is organized in the `mlflow-model` folder, and when registering the model using mlflow, it registers it as `mlflow` model, however, when trying to share the model to `AzureML Model Registry` it fails, as mlflow is looking for a `model` folder.

> ```
> # Get Run ID from model path
> print("Getting model path")
> mlmodel_path = os.path.join(args.model_input_path, "MLmodel")
> runid = ""
> with open(mlmodel_path, "r") as modelfile:
>     for line in modelfile:
>         if "run_id" in line:
>             runid = line.split(":")[1].strip()
>
> # Construct Model URI from run ID extract previously
> model_uri = "runs:/{}/outputs/mlflow-model/".format(runid)
> print("Model URI: " + model_uri)
> mlflow.register_model(model_uri, registered_name)
> ```

The question is how to register the model from `model_uri` as a `custom model` not `mlflow` model?

Answer (score 0):

To register the model from `model_uri` as a `custom model` not `mlflow` model, you can use **AssetTypes Class** from  **[azure.ai.ml.constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-ai-ml/azure.ai.ml.constants.assettypes?view=azure-python)**.

```
# import required libraries
from  azure.identity  import  DefaultAzureCredential
from  azure.ai.ml  import MLClient
from  azure.ai.ml.constants  import  AssetTypes
from  azure.ai.ml.entities  import Model
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
ml_client = None
try:
    ml_client =MLClient.from_config(credential)
except  Exception  as  ex:
    print(ex)
    subscription_id = "<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>"
    resource_group = "<RESOURCE_GROUP>"
    workspace = "<AML_WORKSPACE_NAME>"
    ml_client = MLClient(credential, subscription_id, resource_group, workspace)
model_name = "test-model"
model = Model(
path=f"azureml://jobs/{run.info.run_id}/outputs/artifacts/model/",
name=model_name,
description="my sample model",
type=AssetTypes.CUSTOM_MODEL,
)
registered_model = ml_client.models.create_or_update(model)
```

In the above code snippet, you can configure your **AssetType** from **MLFLOW_MODEL** to **CUSTOM_MODEL**.

**Alternate method** to achieve this is via **mlflow.artifacts.download_artifacts**.
1.Check for the model path in artifact list:

```
client = mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient()
client.list_artifacts(run_id=run.info.run_id)
```

Output:

```
[<FileInfo: file_size=-1, is_dir=False, path='feature_importance_weight.json'>,
<FileInfo: file_size=-1, is_dir=False, path='feature_importance_weight.png'>,
<FileInfo: file_size=-1, is_dir=False, path='metric_info.json'>,
<FileInfo: file_size=-1, is_dir=True, path='model'>]
```

2.Download the model in **tmp**:

```
file_path = mlflow.artifacts.download_artifacts(run_id=run.info.run_id, artifact_path="model")
print(file_path)
```

Output:

```
'/tmp/tmpq7u53_7m/model'
```

3.Register the downloaded model:

```
from  azureml.core  import  Workspace, Model
workspace = Workspace.from_config()

model = Model.register(
model_path=f'/tmp/tmpq7u53_7m/model',#file_path for downloaded model
model_name='model1',
workspace=workspace,
model_framework_version=None    
)
```

By default the model will be register as **custom model**.

Output:

[image]

For more information you can refer [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-ai-ml/azure.ai.ml.constants.assettypes?view=azure-python&viewFallbackFrom=azure-python%29**.)

Comment: This is in my training script and there I do not have credentials, as it is run on compute cluster, yes I can add there user assigned identity, but I was thinking to do it just by using mlflow library